# How do you query for a non-existent (null) attribute in DynamoDB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to query a DynamoDB table to find all items where the `email` attribute is not set. A global secondary index called `EmailPasswordIndex` exists on the table which includes the `email` field.

```
var params = {
    "TableName": "Accounts",
    "IndexName": "EmailPasswordIndex",
    "KeyConditionExpression": "email = NULL",
};

dynamodb.query(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    else
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

Result:

```
{
  "message": "Invalid KeyConditionExpression: Attribute name is a reserved keyword; reserved keyword: NULL",
  "code": "ValidationException",
  "time": "2015-12-18T05:33:00.356Z",
  "statusCode": 400,
  "retryable": false
}
```

Table definition:

```
var params = {
    "TableName": "Accounts",
    "KeySchema": [
        { "AttributeName": "id", KeyType: "HASH" }, // Randomly generated UUID
    ],
    "AttributeDefinitions": [
        { "AttributeName": "id", AttributeType: "S" },
        { "AttributeName": "email", AttributeType: "S" }, // User e-mail.
        { "AttributeName": "password", AttributeType: "S" }, // Hashed password.
    ],
    "GlobalSecondaryIndexes": [
        {
            "IndexName": "EmailPasswordIndex",
            "ProvisionedThroughput": {
                "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
                "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
            },
            "KeySchema": [
                { "AttributeName": "email", KeyType: "HASH" },
                { "AttributeName": "password", KeyType: "RANGE" },
            ],
            "Projection": { "ProjectionType": "ALL" }
        },
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput: {       
        ReadCapacityUnits: 1, 
        WriteCapacityUnits: 1
    }
};

dynamodb.createTable(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    else
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

Comment: Can you provide your table and index attribute definitions?

Comment: @mkobit Added, thanks.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

DynamoDB's Global Secondary Indexes allow for the indexes to be sparse.  That means that if you have a GSI whose hash or range key for an item is not defined then that item will simply not be included in the GSI.  This is useful in a number of use cases as it allows you to directly identify records that contain certain fields.  However, this approach will not work if you are looking for the lack of a field.

To get all of the items that have a field not set your best bet may be resorting to a scan with a filter.  This operation will be very expensive but it would be straightforward code looking something like the following:

```
var params = {
    TableName: "Accounts",
    FilterExpression: "attribute_not_exists(email)"
};

dynamodb.scan(params, {
    if (err)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    else
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
});
```

Answer (score 68):

@jaredHatfield is correct if the field does not exist but that will not work if the filed is null. NULL is a keyword and can't used directly. But you can use it with ExpressionAttributeValues.

```
const params = {
    TableName: "Accounts",
    FilterExpression: "attribute_not_exists(email) or email = :null",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ':null': null
    }
}

dynamodb.scan(params, (err, data) => {
    if (err)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    else
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this precision, I was looking just for that :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's @Mardok's excellent example updated for the v3 sdk and using typescript. Note the usage of the `marshall` function from the `@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb` package.

```js
import { ScanCommand, ScanCommandInput } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
import { marshall } from '@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb';

const input: ScanCommandInput = {
  TableName: 'Accounts',
  FilterExpression: 'attribute_not_exists(email) or email = :null',
  ExpressionAttributeValues: marshall({
    ':null': null,
  }),
};

const command = new ScanCommand(input);
const response = await dbClient.send(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since DynamoDB is what it is, one needs to use non-orthodox approaches to the database usage.

I simply introduced a special value, which may be anything safely recognizable in your domain (e.g. `"--NULL--"`), and convert that from/to `null` at the lowest data layer.

Querying entries with that field null is then just querying for that special value.

It's not nice from a perspective of someone used to SQL, but better than scanning.

For the legacy entries, you will need one-time migration.

Comment: Is this any better than Mardok's answer? If so, why?