# NOT_NULL query condition on globalSecondaryIndex in dynamodb query

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to add constraint to a dynamodb query expression that states that a GSI should be not null?

Can somebody provide examples.

Is possible to construct a query like the one below?

```
new DynamoDBQueryExpression<XXX>()
            .withHashKeyValues(YYY).withKeyConditionExpression(GSI != NULL);
```

Note:
Please let me know if this is possible in during query and not during filter time?

Comment: What do you mean when you say GSI null? attributes or hash/range keys?

Comment: I mean value of the attribute should not be null.

Comment: Could you please provide the sample data? I would like to check whether you meant GSI attribute exist and doesn't have any value and how it is stored in the DynamoDB table?

Answer (score 2):

if you're like me and you landed on this page while finding the answer to the above question, here's the thread you need to see

[How do you query for a non-existent (null) attribute in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349135/how-do-you-query-for-a-non-existent-null-attribute-in-dynamodb)

Answer (score 0):

The **DynamoDB String** attribute can't have NULL or empty string.

When you try to insert NULL, the API should throw the below exception:-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input value must not be null
```

When you try to insert empty string, the API should throw the below exception:-

```
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string
```

If you want to add additional filters on some attributes (i.e. attributes other than hash or range key), you can use the below syntax (i.e. withFilterExpression).

**Not equals operator is "<>"**

```
Map<String, AttributeValue> eav = new HashMap<String, AttributeValue>();
eav.put(":val1", new AttributeValue().withS("Some value"));

DynamoDBQueryExpression<XXX> queryExpression = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<XXX>();
    queryExpression.withHashKeyValues(hashKeyValues);       
    queryExpression.withFilterExpression("docType <> :val1").withExpressionAttributeValues(eav);
```