# DynamoDB: KeyConditionExpression to check if an attribute exists or not null

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am using boto3 to query DynamoDB. And I have heard that `table.query()` is more efficient that `table.scan()`
I was wondering if there is a way to check if the value exists using `query()` method?

```
response = table.scan(FilterExpression=Attr('attribute').exists()
```

If it is not possible to check using `.query()` is there any other method that is more efficient than `.scan()`?

This question is not a duplicate - I am looking for a way to optimize querying for existing/non existing attributes of `.query()` or `.scan()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you query for a non-existent (null) attribute in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349135/how-do-you-query-for-a-non-existent-null-attribute-in-dynamodb)

Comment: @Chris Nauroth I don't think it is a duplicate as it talks about scan() and my question is about query()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `query()` is more efficient than `scan()` because it works with hash key only, and the query must match base table schema. That is the reason for it to be so efficient.

Therefore it is not possible to `scan()` for attributes that are not in the base schema.

Answer (score 0):

As it is said by @BanzaiTokyo, the `query()` method is more efficient than `scan()` because it simply does not search from top to bottom but instead it **relies on** PK and SK.

These documentation explain and shows very well the Boto3 functions using conditions on **KeyConditions** or **FilterExpressions**.

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/_modules/boto3/dynamodb/conditions.html

Therefore, to check if a value exists we should use the `attribute_exists(path)` function, where `path` is the attribute in your DynamoDB table.

```
response = table.query(
  FilterExpression: 'attribute_exists(USER)' #USER is the name of the attribute
)
```

Remember to specify the table name and the query can be combined with **KeyConditionExpression** to facilitate the search.