# Dynamo DB - scan with filter to return entries where column is not null

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I want to run scan on a Dynamo DB database and get all entries where a specific column is not null.

Saw this post [How do you query for a non-existent (null) attribute in DynamoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34349135/how-do-you-query-for-a-non-existent-null-attribute-in-dynamodb)

and I tried this - but it does not return any results.

Here's my query:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name some_table_name --projection-expression "id, email, name" --condition-expression "attribute_exists(activation_date)"
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `aws dynamodb scan` does not have any parameter called `--condition-expression`, and is probably ignored. The parameter you're looking for is `--filter-expression`.